# For loop over unique values is not working

Tags: r

I know that this problem was allready the topic of some questions and i tried it the same way but i get not the results iam looking for... iam sure somebody can help me with my problem;) here a small example:

In my "result matrix" i get in each colum the same values but i need the vaules for each m???

thanks in advance.

```
n=5
result = matrix(NA,ncol = 3 ,nrow = 5)
y=cbind(3,5,6,7,9)
mth = c(1,5,10)
  for(m in 1:length(unique(mth))){
if (m==1)   {d0 = 2}
if (m==5)   {d0 = 5}
if (m==10)   {d0 = 9 }
result[,m] = d0%*% y}
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: m is a counter getting values 1, 2, 3. It never reaches 5, so obviously you get always the same numbers. replace `m` with `mth[m]` inside your loop and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think you messed up the index and the values of `mth`.

If you say `for(m in 1:length(unique(mth)))`, `m` will take the values `1 2 3` since the vector `mth` has a length of `3`.

I added indexing to the `mth` vector of your code (e.g. `mth[m]` will give you the first value of `mth` when `m` is `1` in the first iteration and so on), now it should give you your expected result.

```
n=5
result = matrix(NA,ncol = 3 ,nrow = 5)
y=cbind(3,5,6,7,9)
mth = c(1,5,10)

for(m in 1:length(unique(mth))){
  if (mth[m]==1)   {d0 = 2}
  if (mth[m]==5)   {d0 = 5}
  if (mth[m]==10)   {d0 = 9 }
  result[,m] = d0%*% y}
```